# UINavigation issue in App

Tags: ios, swift

i have multiple storyboard in my storyboard. I have embedded the firstVC with navigationcontroller and remaining attached to the firstvc through segues. The remaining VC's are not embedded in navigationcontroller. Now when i click the button to open the next VC without navigation controller. It opens it twice. When i disconnect the segue it does not open the VC. I'm confused that why this is happening so. This is how my UI Looks,
[image]

This is how i perform the segue,

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToNextVC", sender: self)
```

Comment: Are you using the navigation bar in the view controllers after firstVC?

Comment: yes previously i have embedded them with navigation controller, than i removed that and setup this scenario. @NeilHiddink

Comment: I guess you have connected the button to the next screen using segues and also calling it through code.

Comment: No, i have connected from firstVC to the next using show of segue and given identifier and calling it through identifier only. The segue is not from button. @KeshuRai

Comment: Did you by any chance connected the open button directly to the next vc in storyboard? (select the button in storyboard and check the connections inspector and see if triggered segues has an action)

Comment: no, i have have checked it, there no sugue connected to button directly. @giorashc

Comment: GoToNextVC sounds general. did you use it on the other segues as well?

Comment: No, every segue has their own identifier. @giorashc

Comment: If you comment out the performSegue call do you get a single transition or none?

Comment: when i comment the performsegue line it does not perform any transition. @vacawama

Answer (score 0):

**View Controllers operate on a stack hierarchy.** By embedding your first view controller in a UINavigationController and setting that as the **Initial View Controller**, you're making it the root view controller for the whole stack. The issue you are experiencing is occurring because you are segueing to view controllers without the root view controller's knowledge every time you call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`. This causes the stack to be out of order and disjointed, preventing you from returning to the previous view controller(s) when calling `dismiss(animated:completion:)`.

Instead of segues, try pushing each view controller to the stack with:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(VIEW_CONTROLLER, animated: true)
```

To use this:

- Remove any segues in Interface Builder, they are no longer needed.
- Replace `VIEW_CONTROLLER` with the view controller you want to push.

Comment: what this line means? Replace VIEW_CONTROLLER with the view controller you want to push. @Neil Hiddink

Comment: Bro i have used this code but still it is opening it twice. let first = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"VerifyAccountVC") as! VerifyAccountVC
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(first, animated: true). @Neil Hiddink

Comment: Do you have multiple view controllers with the same identifier?

Comment: Xcode is showing me 9 error related to designable, it might be due to that? @Neil Hiddink

Comment: i have tried all of these but still it is happening . @Neil Hiddink